# Trying to build and run vscode for contribution but the code.bat script doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-code

I forked the [vscode repo](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode) and `yarn` and `ctrl` + `shift` + `b`. Then I try to run the bash files to open the new vscode window like in [this video](https://youtu.be/W_xau3w4GJo?t=181). But the problem is, the bash files doesn't run properly.

This is the code from the [vscode docs](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/wiki/How-to-Contribute#desktop):

```
.\scripts\code.bat
.\scripts\code-cli.bat
```

First I need to replace `\` with `/`, like this:

```
./scripts/code.bat
./scripts/code-cli.bat
```

I copy paste the new code to the vscode bash terminal, it throws this error:

```
node ➜ /workspaces/vscode $ ./scripts/code.bat
./scripts/code-cli.bat

bash: ./scripts/code.bat: Permission denied
bash: ./scripts/code-cli.bat: Permission denied
```

I find this solution from google:

```
chmod u+x ./scripts/code.bat
chmod u+x ./scripts/code-cli.bat
```

I copy paste the code once again and it throws this new error:

```
node ➜ /workspaces/vscode $ ./scripts/code.bat
./scripts/code-cli.bat

./scripts/code.bat: line 1: @echo: command not found
./scripts/code.bat: line 2: $'setlocal\r': command not found
./scripts/code.bat: line 3: $'\r': command not found
./scripts/code.bat: line 4: title: command not found
./scripts/code.bat: line 5: $'\r': command not found
./scripts/code.bat: line 6: pushd: $'%~dp0..\r': No such file or directory
./scripts/code.bat: line 7: $'\r': command not found
./scripts/code.bat: line 8: ::: command not found
./scripts/code.bat: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `"tokens=2 delims=:,"'
./scripts/code.bat: line 11: `for /f "tokens=2 delims=:," %%a in ('fi'dstr /R /C:"\"nameShort\":.*" product.json') do set NAMESHORT=%%~a
./scripts/code-cli.bat: line 1: @echo: command not found
./scripts/code-cli.bat: line 2: $'setlocal\r': command not found
./scripts/code-cli.bat: line 3: $'\r': command not found
./scripts/code-cli.bat: line 4: title: command not found
./scripts/code-cli.bat: line 5: $'\r': command not found
./scripts/code-cli.bat: line 6: pushd: $'%~dp0..\r': No such file or directory
./scripts/code-cli.bat: line 7: $'\r': command not found
./scripts/code-cli.bat: line 8: ::: command not found
./scripts/code-cli.bat: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `"tokens=2 delims=:,"'
./scripts/code-cli.bat: line 11: `for /f "tokens=2 delims=:," %%a in ('findstr /R /C:"\"nameShort\":.*" product.json') do set NAMESHORT=%%'a
```

This is my vscode info:

```
Version: 1.77.3 (user setup)
Commit: 704ed70d4fd1c6bd6342c436f1ede30d1cff4710
Date: 2023-04-12T09:16:02.548Z
Electron: 19.1.11
Chromium: 102.0.5005.196
Node.js: 16.14.2
V8: 10.2.154.26-electron.0
OS: Windows_NT x64 10.0.19045
Sandboxed: Yes
```

This is all of my Visual Studio apps installed:

[image]

Do I need to install something or what? What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: UPDATE: I build the thing directly without using dev containers or anything like that and now it works as expected. Thanks to (Alireza Safaeirad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't run it in the bash shell. Instead, you should run it in `PowerShell` or `CMD` since it's an MS Windows batch file.

Comment: I build the thing directly without using dev containers or anything like that and now it works as expected. Thanks to (Alireza Safaeirad).